# How to create new columns parallely in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, parallel-processing

The question is that in my project I have a very large number of variables, and each of them must generate a different set of data, depending on its characteristics. In the end I need to create a dataframe from scratch with a column for each of these variables, but this is a complex operation that I would like to run using parallel computing.

For the sake of simplicity let me share a minimal code example of what I want.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Variable:
    def __init__(self, name: str, size: int):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
    def generate(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.random.uniform(size=self.size)

a, b, c = Variable("a", 10), Variable("b", 10), Variable("c", 10)

df = pd.DataFrame() # dataframe initialization

# I WANT TO PARALLELIZE THIS LOOP
for variable in (a, b, c):
    df[variable.name] = variable.generate()

print(df)
          a         b         c
0  0.718582  0.878755  0.915133
1  0.219730  0.138247  0.026435
2  0.103152  0.696209  0.014087
3  0.037164  0.546629  0.748382
4  0.450409  0.022785  0.775490
5  0.403478  0.807022  0.608785
6  0.123544  0.981992  0.798302
7  0.393683  0.661545  0.064831
8  0.744600  0.484391  0.913605
9  0.551722  0.167203  0.213266
```

Would be possible to afford this task by using multiprocessing, joblib or another related packages?

Comment: You can use pyspark for this;

Comment: I know it, but mi question is about Pandas, not pyspark

Comment: Hi, instead of adding columns to an empty dataframe, why don't you set them up in a dictionary first, then make a dataframe of if? This will be much faster without the need  for a concurrent approach (which won't be more efficient btw)?